# PayPal Parallel Payment dynamic receiver/amounts

Tags: php, paypal

I am having difficulty figuring out how to create an array of information for sending parallel payment information to PayPal.  When a user shops on my website, they can add multiple items to their shopping cart from different sellers.  I need the store information to be pulled based on the sellers information for each item in the cart and the corresponding amount for each seller's item.

This is the code for the paypal parallel payment:

```
$receiverEmailArray = array(
'roy.ym_1346651928_biz@gmail.com',
'webdev_1335179182_biz@gmail.com',
);

$receiverAmountArray = array(
$_POST['store1'],
$_POST['store2']
);
```

I need the receiverEmailArray to pull the information based on dynamic information from the cart session (instead of roy.ym_1346651928_biz@gmail.com) and the receiverAmountArray from the cart session (instead of 'store1')

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using `$_SESSION['']` to store the information?